# Do data source credentials in Excel Power Query expire?

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

Sometimes users are asked for credentials when trying to refresh queries, even though they have entered credentials before.  I'm wondering if the credentials can expire.  Data sources include SQL Server and Sharepoint list.

Edit: Sorry I wasn't being clear at first. I am referring to the credentials entered in Excel so that the workbook can connect to a data source.  Once entered, Excel remembers the credentials, but sometimes the window in the screenshot would pop up and ask for credentials again, even though the credentials are still valid, so I wonder whether Excel would forget credentials after certain time period.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYMVk.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Each data source may have a different administrator who determines credentials expiration policies. Some data sources will use single sign-on which then bases access by which user is signed on to excel. There may be other options that I am not familiar with as an end user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you connect to SharePoint or SQL server, Power Query is not actually storing your credentials.

When you login, it creates a token which is used later to authenticate connection.
When the token is expired - as your password is not stored - you need to login again.

Comment: That makes sense.  Kind of like web authentication.  Thank you!